# Define variable with IF ELSE statement - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

I'm trying to define and output a `$store_icon` variable based on the IF ELSE condition.

I'd like to show a store icon if the store icon image exists, if it doesn't, then I'd like to show just a regular profile avatar (using an existing shortcode)

This is as far as I can get:

```
$store_icon_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_user_meta( $vendor_id, '_wcv_store_icon_id', true ), array( 40, 40  ) ); 
$store_icon     = '';

if ( is_array( $store_icon_src ) && !empty($store_icon_src) ) {
     $store_icon = '<img src="'. $store_icon_src[0].'" alt="Store Name" class="store-icon" width="40" height="40" />';
} else {
     $store_icon = do_shortcode( '[profile-avatar]' );
}

echo '<div class="store-icon">'. $store_icon .'</div>';
```

It kinda works, but I need both options to be output inside the echo html div tags.

Currently they're not, the first option seems to be called outside the echo.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I came across to 'Ternary operator' from another question, so I'm trying this:

```
$store_icon   = (is_array( $store_icon_src ) && !empty($store_icon_src) ) ? '<img src="'. $store_icon_src[0].'" alt="My Store" class="store-icon" width="40" height="40" />' : do_shortcode( '[profile-avatar]' );
```

And then output:

```
ob_start();
echo '<div class="store-icon">'. $store_icon .'</div>';
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
```

But nothing changed, the first `img` is still called outside the echo div tags.

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: It should be outputting the defined $store_icon inside the div tags, I've updated my question.

Comment: What's it outputting?